# Django Tests User Object

Tags: python, django

I'm testing a django app from this tutorial: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_admin/README.html

I've created a test:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your tests here.
class PostTest(TestCase):
    def test_create_post(self):
        # Create the post
        post = Post()

        # Set the attributes
        post.author = User
        post.title = 'My first post'
        post.text = 'This is my first blog post'
        post.published_date = timezone.now()
        post.created_date = timezone.now()

        # Save it
        post.save()

        # Check we can find it
        all_posts = Post.objects.all()
        self.assertEquals(len(all_posts), 1)
        only_post = all_posts[0]
        self.assertEquals(only_post, post)

        # Check attributes
        self.assertEquals(only_post.author, User)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.title, 'My first post')
        self.assertEquals(only_post.text, 'This is my first blog post')
        self.assertEquals(only_post.published_date.day, post.published_date.day)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.published_date.month, post.published_date.month)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.published_date.year, post.published_date.year)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.published_date.hour, post.published_date.hour)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.published_date.minute, post.published_date.minute)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.published_date.second, post.published_date.second)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.created_date.day, post.created_date.day)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.created_date.month, post.created_date.month)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.created_date.year, post.created_date.year)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.created_date.hour, post.created_date.hour)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.created_date.minute, post.created_date.minute)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.created_date.second, post.created_date.second)
```

When I run `python manage.py test` I get this error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

ERROR: test_create_post (blog.tests.PostTest)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File     "C:\Users\shenk\Documents\Programming\django_projects\djangogirls\blog\tests.py"    , line 13, in test_create_post
post.author = User
File      "c:\Users\shenk\Documents\Programming\django_projects\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 627, in __set__
self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>":     "Post.author" must be a "User" instance.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
```

How can I create an object of User instance to test the Post?  In my model it's defined as `author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line looks bogus:

```
# Set the attributes
post.author = User
```

post.author is expecting for you to assign an *instance* of the User class to it, not the User class itself. Try something like:

```
u = User(...)
u.save()
post.author = u
```

Comment: Was following a tutorial, and trying to fix the issues.  They had that line there.  Thank You.